# Fancybox customize specified thumb

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I using fancyBox v3.5.6.
I need to add a CSS class/id/style-attribute to a specific thumb element. I can't do this with changing template, because it will change all thumbs and there is no logic with count of thumbs, and then i can't use css pseudoselectors like last-child or nth-child. I didn't find solution in fancy docs and googling.
Here is an example https://prnt.sc/qqmwbz

Comment: So i find some crazy CSS solution. We can styling thumb by end of background-image url, adding get parameter.


.fancybox-thumbs__list a[style$="?youtube-placeholder=1)"]

Answer (score 1):

Inspect thumbnail elements, each of them has has `data-index` attribute (for example, `data-index="1"`), you can use that to do some customization.

Comment: I know about it, thank you, but indexes of elements can change (thumbs count can changes)

Comment: You could also use callbacks to retrieve fancybox instance and then you can easily access all elements (for example, `$.fancybox.getInstance().Thumbs.$list.children().eq(3)`)